# AJAX xhr onprogress messages buffered on some devices

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

A PHP script is outputting progress text messages that should get displayed as they arrive in a browser.  The browser receives them in AJAX xhr.onprogress.  On a couple of my laptops these messages are somehow buffered and not displayed until the last one is sent. On my phone it works correctly. It is working correctly for other users.  I've run it with a remote server and also locally with an Apache server with the same results. I get the same bad results in 3 different browsers. Running it locally seems to rule out network issues. I've turned off firewalls and backup services and get the same results.  There seems to be a setting on the offending computers that cause this.  Below is my test code followed by expected and received results.  Any ideas?
Many thanks!

HTML/Javascript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><link rel="shortcut icon" href="#"></head>
<style>
  .msg_area {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 500px;
    width: 80%;
  }
</style>

<body>
<div>
  <label for="messages">Progress messages</label>
  <br>
  <div class="msg_area" id="messages"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js"></script>
<script>

  function debug(msg) {
    msg = msg.replace(/"/g, "");   // remove quotes
    msg = msg.replace(/\\n/g, "<br>");  // replace \n with html <br>
    $("#messages").append(msg);
  }

  function AJAXCall(the_url) {
    var n = 0;
    $.ajax({
      url: the_url, 
      async: true,
      beforeSend: function() {        
        //debug("BeforeSend:\n" + the_msg);
      },
      xhrFields: {
        onprogress: function(e) {
          // All the messages come through onprogress. and each text is the accumulated message over all sends.
          // We just want to print the new part so we keep track of the length of everything printed so far in variable n
          // The last message will be a stringified JSON object with 'success' as the first key
          var i;
          //  does this message contain the success object?
          if((i = e.target.responseText.indexOf("{\"success", n)) == -1) {
            // no success object, print it out
            debug("PROGRESS:  " + e.target.responseText.substr(n));
            n = e.target.responseText.length;
          } else {
            // found success object.  Print out up to that obejct and set n to the start of that string
            debug("PROGRESS:SUCCESS: " + e.target.responseText.substr(n, i-n));
            debug("=====================================\n");
            n = i;
          }
        }
      },
      error: function (request, status, error) {
        debug("ERROR:  "+ request.responseText);
      }
    });
  }

AJAXCall("http://localhost/test_ajax.php");

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

for($i=0; $i<3; $i++) {
  msg("Message $i\n");
  sleep(3);
}
echo json_encode(array("success" => true, "text" => "end test_ajax.php"));

function msg($text) {
  global $first_msg;

  echo json_encode($text);
  flush();
  ob_flush();
}

?>
```

Correct results (on my phone and other's computers):

```
PROGRESS: Message 0
PROGRESS: Message 1
PROGRESS:SUCCESS: Message 2
=====================================
```

Bad buffered results (my laptop):

```
PROGRESS:SUCCESS: Message 0 
Message 1 
Message 2
=====================================
```

Comment: maybe use vanilla javascript, and try fetch instead of XHR. Could help at least as a test, and jQuery doesn't really seem to be needed here at all.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't see how fetch will do what an AJAX call will.  Fetch is more of an SQL result thing and the client needs to know how many results there are,  In my case the server side is sending messages and the client does not know what to expect.  jQuery is left over from my larger app, sorry, this is boiled down.

Comment: `Fetch is more of an SQL result thing`....not sure where you got that idea. Fetch makes an ajax request, just like XHR and just like jquery's $.ajax. The only difference is it's more modern and easier to use than XHR, and it's built into every modern browser so you don't need to load a library like jquery to use it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: You are so right. I was seeing the PDOStatement::fetch. I'll check it out. I'm still dumbfounded at why my code works on others machines but not mine.